# Proving upper bounds on the quality of a TSP heuristic

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am reading a paper regarding [TSP approximations](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=314489). Specifically, the authors claim that running the 2-opt heuristic on a metric TSP problem yields a $4\sqrt{n}$-approximate solution for a graph with $n$ vertices.
Specifically, the authors consider a tour $T$ which is 2-opt and introduce the sets

$$
E_k := \{e \in T \mid c(e) > \frac{2 c(T_{\text{opt}})}{\sqrt{k}}\}
$$

The authors go on to show that $|E_k| < k$. Intuitively, there are not that many really expensive edges. Presumably this fact helps to prove the approximation quality.

Each edge $e \in T$ is assumed to be directed according to the tour $T$, it therefore has a head vertex $h(e)$ and a tail vertex $t(e)$. The authors argue that any ball $B$ of radius $c(T_{\text{opt}})/\sqrt{k}$ has at most $\sqrt{k}$ edges with tails in $B$.

This is the part that I am stuck on. The definition of a ball in metric space is as far as I know given by $B(v, r) := \{ w \in V \mid d(v, w) \leq r \}$ where $d$ is the corresponding metric.

Since $T$ is 2-opt, no improvement is possible using a 2-opt move implying that for all $e, f \in T$ it holds that

$$
  c(e) + c(f) \leq d(t(e), t(f)) + d(h(e), h(f))
$$

We also have that $c(e), c(f) > 2 c(T_{\text{opt}}) / \sqrt{k}$.

For $e, f$ with tails in $B(v, c(T_{\text{opt}})/\sqrt{k})$ for some $v \in V$ we can conclude that

$$
  d(t(e), t(f)) \leq d(t(e), v) + d(t(f), v) \leq 2 
  \frac{c(T_{\text{opt}})}{\sqrt{k}}
$$

This makes it possible to conclude that for all $e, f \in E_k$ and tails in $B(v, c(T_{\text{opt}})/\sqrt{k})$

$$
  d(h(e), h(f)) > 2 \frac{c(T_{\text{opt}})}{\sqrt{k}}
$$

So we know that the heads of these edges are also far apart.

The authors write that the fact that there are at most $\sqrt{k}$ edges in
$E_k$ with tails in $B(v, c(T_{\text{opt}})/\sqrt{k})$

> [...] follows because otherwise there would be a pair of
>   edges from $E_k$ whose heads were close enough to admit an improving
>   2-change.

I really can't follow that argument. Yes, the heads are far apart, but the edges themselves can also be arbitrarily long, so even if there are a lot of such tails in a small ball, that does not really lead to a contradiction.

Comment: 2 remarks: 1) The article is not accessible. 2) It has been written 23 years ago. A good lot of improvements have been done on this classical problem since that.

Comment: Oh, that is a shame. I don't know if the improvements are really that substantial in that case. The paper basically establishes a tight bound on the quality of k-opt.